# Auto-switch sound to Bluetooth audio device upon connection? (macOS 12.6)

Tags: audio, bluetooth

OS X used to auto-switch sound output to Bluetooth when connected. MacOS 12.6.1 no longer does this (on a MacBook Air M2). Does anyone know how to get the operating system to do this automatically?

Others have suggested using custom scripts or 3rd-party software. I'm seeking a solution built into the operating system, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. No such mechanism exists in macOS, much as we'd like it too. I've never seen this as an option in the past few versions of macOS. You might want to submit [Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) to Apple and make a request to have this option in a future version macOS. I've submitted this request (and many others) in the past.

There are scripts which will do this, but I've not investigated myself. After all, it's only a few mouse movements and clicks to connect a Bluetooth device. I do it automatically now without really thinking about it.

Comment: The funny thing is, people wanted macOS [stop auto switching to the BT headphones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/88884/119271).